# UNABLE to POST data to WCF from Android

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, wcf, web-services

I'm trying to send data to WCF service from an Android Application but somehow the service doesn't seems to be call through the android. I received a **STATUSCODE** value = 500 through adnroid in **LOGCAT** (which means the Internal Server Error) I go through the source code 100 times but didn't figure out the Bug. and almost checked all the posts related to my problem but still didn't get any solution.

**HERE IS THS CODE**

Android Code:

```
private class sendPostData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    HttpPost request = new HttpPost( LOGIN_SERVICE_URL + "/MyCar");
    request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");            
    request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    JSONStringer getCarInfo;
    try {
        getCarInfo = new JSONStringer()
            .object()
                .key("myCar")
                    .object()
                        .key("Name").value(edt_carName.getText().toString())                                  
                        .key("Make").value(edt_carMake.getText().toString())
                        .key("Model").value(edt_carModel.getText().toString())
                    .endObject()
                .endObject();

    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(getCarInfo.toString());

    request.setEntity(entity);

    // Send request to WCF service
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    Log.d("WebInvoke", "Saving : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    txt_verif.setText("Success");
}
}
```

everything is working fine in android code except calling the WCF service. I **Debug** the code several times and received statuscode = 500

**HERE is the WCF Service**

**Service.cs**

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public void UpdateMyCar(myCar myCar) {

        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database1"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into TestingTable (Name,Make,Model) Values (@Name,@Make,@Model)", conn)) {

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", myCar.Name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Make", myCar.Make);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Model", myCar.Model);

            int queryResult = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        } conn.Close();
    }
```

**LogCat**

```
WebInvoke     Saving : 500
```

**IService1.svc**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "MyCar",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void UpdateMyCar(myCar myCar);
}

[DataContract]
public class myCar 
{

    [DataMember(Name="Name")]
    public string Name 
    { 
        get; 
       set; 
    }

    [DataMember(Name="Model")]
    public string Model 
    { 
        get; 
        set; 
    }

    [DataMember(Name="Make")]
    public string Make 
    { 
        get;
        set; 
    }
```

**Web.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
<appSettings/>
<connectionStrings/>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/></system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="CarSercive.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="CarSercive.Service1Behavior">
            <!-- Service Endpoints -->
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="CarSercive.IService1">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="CarSercive.Service1Behavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>

                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

this service is also publish on IIS. and I also checked that service with google chrome extension **SIMPLE REST CLIENT** and received an internal server error

Comment: What does SIMPLE REST CLIENT show as the response body? WCF will tell you the error detail, and we need that info.

Comment: thanks for your response. I'm getting this

http://localhost:8259/Service1.svc/MyCar' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree

Comment: @GregEnnis I have made some chances in my web.config file. I changed **Binding = "webHttpBinding" to "wsHttpBinding"** so the **statuscode** has changed to **415**

Comment: Have you considered using Web API instead of WCF? That is much easier to configure. Status 415 means unspported media type (json)

Comment: no i didn't considered any Web API. but my WCF service **RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json** is also in JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I have made several changes in **web.config** file and got the solution. `<endpointBehaviors>` **tag** was missing in my case and several other things. here is the updated code of **web.config** file.

[**UPDATED web.config file**]

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="DB" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Munyb\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CarSercive\CarSercive\App_Data\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/></system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="CarSercive.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="RESTfulServ">
            <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="CarSercive.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="RESTfulServ">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>

    </behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
</system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"> 
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your host name doesn't match what you are using from the phone.

You can turn off address filter to fix this temporarily:

```
[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode=AddressFilterMode.Any)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    ....
}
```

But you should fix the hostname when you release to production

Comment: This does fix the error you posted. You are getting a different error now. What is it?

Comment: yeah @Greg Ennis im getting a different error now.

cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

Answer (score 0):

Create a domain in your machine with proper port number and make sure you are able to call the service using the Google's Rest client.If it works,then you won't find any issue if you call the same using your android phone.

Following article will help to setup virtual directory with proper port number.[http://www.hosting.com/support/iis7/create-new-sites-in-iis-7/]

**Note** you can't call localhost directly from your mobile.atleast try to call the service with ipaddress.[http://localhost/service/mycar] =>[http://DemoService/service/mycar]

Comment: thanks for your response I'm not testing that an android phone. I'm test that service on an emulator and that emulator works for other services.

Comment: I'm getting the same response in the Google extension. 500 (internal server error )

Comment: I hope the following code will help you to debug a little bit more.I think you are getting some exception in your code or somewhere ti fails.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will help you to debug your code a little bit deep.

```
catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WebException webexception = (WebException)ex;
                var responseresult = webexception.Response as HttpWebResponse;

                //Code to debug Http Response
                var responseStream = webexception.Response.GetResponseStream();
                string fault_message = string.Empty;
                int lastNum = 0;
                do
                {
                    lastNum = responseStream.ReadByte();
                    fault_message += (char)lastNum;
                } while (lastNum != -1);
                responseStream.Close();
}
```