# Best way to synchronize files between android and windows

Tags: c#, java, android, windows, web-services

i have a C# pogram to execute Checklists on Windows.
Now i'm working on an Android App to execute this checklists too.

Now i need a service or something else to synchronize the checklists between the windows program ad the Android app.

Maybe i write a WebService für the App but i found nothing about hosting a Java-WebServices on Android (for the local network). Because the Android device and the PC are always in the same network.

Maybe someone of you have a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `WebServices` for communication between an Android with C#. Now it's up to you which services is usable or more helpful for you. RESTful or SOAP? And for testing your service you can simply use `IIS` or a google chrome extension **SIMPLE REST CLINET**

for `WCF-Services` you can follow this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide). and for more details you can also read this [tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21203484/unable-to-post-data-to-wcf-from-android). this is related with your work.

This [tutorial](http://wyousuf.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/android-with-wcf-services/) will also very helpful :).

Thank